Add a git-<subcmd> on Windows
I have git for windows installed, which includes bash.exe. On Unix systems, I have a Bash script named git-myScript that when available in $PATH, allows me to run commands like these:
git myScript <args>
git --no-pager myScript <args>

Is there a way to "port" my Bash script to Windows? I don't only want to create a PowerShell script named git-myScript.ps that will call the git-myScript bash script, because I want the ability to add general git option arguments before the myScript argument.

When installing GIT, in the Adjusting your PATH environment, did you select Git from the command line and also 3rd party software.  Note that the git commands will work from cmd prompt but may or may not work from powershell.  Could you also post an example of what could be in myScript

A simple solution is to copy the script to $git-installation-path/usr/bin. In git-bash (run as the admin), you can use cp git-myScript /usr/bin. In my git-bash, /usr/bin is in $PATH (check it by echo $PATH). You can copy it to another path in $PATH.
I run a test with a simple script and save it as /usr/bin/git-hello.
#!/bin/bash

echo hello world

In git-bash, CMD and PowerShell, run git hello and it prints hello world as expected.

Thanks for the answer. Your answer led me to write my own, slightly better version.

The following answer assumes you use a sufficiently new PowerShell.
Find a place to put your script, say: C:\Users\<username>\scripts and add first that path to your $env:Path with (credit):
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";" + $env:HOME + "\scripts", "User")

Then, put your script in the C:\Users\<username>\scripts directory, and then add to that directory the following git-myScript.bat file:
@ECHO OFF
bash.exe %~dp0\git-myScript %*

Git should pick it up now, if your $env:Path includes the scripts directory.
